# Object need to be accessed global,static variable or Application contx

Tags: android

I want to have an object accessed by multiple activities and multiple other classes (non activities). I read that a standard way would be to use the application context to store these global variables. However the problem I find with this is that you have to always find this application context. In activities it is not so bad but if you are in a non activity class then you have to pass in the context to it. Kinda pain.

The other solution I have in mind is to create a static variable that I can access from anywhere but just calling "className.Variable"

Is it bad to do it this way? Is there any other method that can work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that "other solution" a static class to be more flexible. No reason to call that 'bad'.

Comment: There's always someone who will call it bad :-) There's a lot that can be said about this topic. Best to just research it. Its out there.

Comment: Right. But notice I said no /reason/

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton design pattern in this case. It's works like magic because you wrap your object into a static class which will be loaded initially by JVM. But pay close attention to threads, if you want to access and modify object state from multiple threads at the same time it can cause problems. In this case you need synchronized or volatile modifiers to prevent bugs. Hope this helps.